# Express res.json creating ID properties I didn't make

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a super simple express route like so:

```
const Router = require('express-promise-router');
const router = Router();

const db = [
  {
    id: 1,
    A: 'a1',
    B: 'b1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    A: 'a2',
    B: 'b2',
  }
]

router.get('/databaseTest', randomMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  res.json(db);
});
```

Yet the response gives me:

```
{
0: {id: 1, A: "a1", B: "b1"}
1: {id: 2, A: "a2", B: "b2" }
}
```

This makes it really inconvenient for me to grab values from these objects... Could somebody help me why express is creating these IDs?

Comment: should send as json `res.json(db)`

Comment: @charlietfl this used to be required in older versions of Express, but not anymore, `res.send` is [capable of handling arrays](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send) and converts them to JSON automatically. Jpark, what you are looking at is a representation created by your browser (just tested it). You're really getting an Array

Comment: @charlietfl just tried it, still giving me the same problem :(

Comment: @blex Didn't realize they were now interchangeable. Thx

Comment: Your issue really sounds like you don't know how to iterate arrays to access each object. What exactly are you trying to do that is giving you problems?

Comment: @charlietfl I guess it's not really a problem, but more wondering why it's giving me this unexpected behavior

Comment: I think you are just misinterpreting what you see in the console. What does it look like when you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData))`?